# Попиксельное сравнение набора прямоугольников изображения cv::Rect opencv

Tags: c++, json, opencv

У меня есть 2 набора прямоугольников cv::Rect, эталонный и тот, что выдает программа. Как я могу попиксельно сравнивая эти два набора на изображении, на котором была проведена разметка, найти пересечние над объединением (Iou) методами opencv, c++?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не совсем понятно, если нужен поиск картинки в другой картинке смотрите `cv::matchTemplate()`

Comment: есть изображение, на котором проводилось обнаружение объектов руками (ручная разметка) и готовой программой, которая имела ошибочные обнаружения. В иттоге у меня два набора прямоугольников - эталонные и последние. И нужно найти пересечение над объединением попиксельно, те проветси регрессионное тестирование